# Why does least squares linear regression perform so bad when switching from 2D to 3D line?

Tags: python, linear-regression

The vector of coefficients that minimize least squares can be found like so:

```
beta = ((X'X)^-1)*X'y
```

Theoretically this result is true for any number of variables (columns of X).

I have made two python notebooks: one for [univariate linear regression](https://github.com/Pign4/ScratchML/blob/master/Linear%20Regression.ipynb) and another one for [multivariate linear regression](https://github.com/Pign4/ScratchML/blob/master/Multivariate%20Linear%20Regression.ipynb).

The code is analogous for both notebooks:

- create a random line

```py
# multivariate snippet. A part from the plotting part,
# this is the only part of the code that differs between the two notebooks.
beta = np.random.randint(1,6,(3,))
X = np.linspace([1, 3, 7],[1, 14, 23],100)
y = X @ beta
```

- create noise

```py
mu, sigma = 0, 1
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 100)
```

- add noise to y

```py
y_noise = y + noise
```

- try to fit a line trough y_noise

```py
beta_ = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y_noise
y_ = X @ beta_
```

- compare y_ with y_noise

[image]
[image]

Why do I get such a different result when fitting a 2D line and a 3D one?

Comment: Do you include a vector with 1,1...1 as first column in your X matrix? This is the intercept and is required to get a proper fit.

Comment: Yes I do, in both cases. In fact in the 2D case the fit is pretty good

Comment: Your numbers don't look very big, but try to normalize your data (e.g. divide by the maximum) in any case. Linear regressions minimize the MSE ($(y-\hat y)^2$) therefore if you have a big y, say y=100, and a small y, say y=0, it will focus on the y=100 because the deviation has a higher impact on the residual.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix $X^TX$ in your example is close to a singular:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv, det

print(det(X.T @ X))

1.479949989718308e-06
```

which makes its inverse very large

```
inv(X.T @ X)

[[ 4.83118746e+11  2.66548273e+11 -1.83251938e+11]
 [ 2.66548273e+11  1.47061116e+11 -1.01104517e+11]
 [-1.83251938e+11 -1.01104517e+11  6.95093558e+10]]
```

This is the reason of the error in your question. The following expression

```
inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ X
```

should produce an identity matrix. But in your example it is

```
[[ 1.2265625   1.10289171  4.8378709 ]
 [ 0.02282715  0.61713325  0.95782902]
 [-0.01519775  0.25675456  0.33339437]]
```

So, when you multiply this matrix by `beta` the result is far from `beta`.

Another way to look at this singularity is that your 3D problem is not actually 3D. It is still 2D. That's why you have a line, not a 2D surface in your plot. It can be converted to a 2D representation by a transformation of coordinates. If you make a matrix for a proper 3D problem, say

```
np.random.seed(3)
X = np.hstack((np.ones((100,1)),np.random.rand(100,2)*100))
```

then `inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ X` gives the correct result:

```
[[ 1.00000000e+00 -1.24233956e-13 -6.21724894e-14]
 [-1.90819582e-17  1.00000000e+00  6.38378239e-16]
 [-8.67361738e-18  9.28077060e-16  1.00000000e+00]]
```

and the formula $\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ works well.